# Simple lab setup in Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: router

I've just started my journey into the netowrking world. I am following Ross Bagurdes course of CCNA.
I am trying to setup a simple lab in Cisco Packet Tracer. To see the lab please check the picture that I've attached.

I've assigned the ip addresses and their submasks as the diagram shows.
The interfaces on the router are in an up state.

I can ping from 10.0.0.10 to 10.0.0.1 but I cannot ping from 10.0.0.10 to 10.0.0.129 or to 10.0.0.130.
I can also ping from 10.0.0.130 to 10.0.0.129 but I cannot ping from 10.0.0.130 to 10.0.0.1 or to 10.0.0.10. [image]

What is it that I am doing wrong? I made sure that I've followed the instructions from the course. Could it be from the Cisco Packet Tracer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End nodes require a route across the router - either a specific route for the other network (e.g. nodes on 10.0.0.0/25: 10.0.0.128/25 -> 10.0.0.1) or just the default route.

Comment: You are right! I forgot to set the default gateway for my end devices.